# Home made apple pie using everclear (dilution of spirits)

Tags: cider

So Ive been hearing alot about this home recipe ppl are making called apple pie. Which just from the name grabbed my attintion. So a buddy gave me some and it was supposed to be high proof stuff which was the 2nd reason it grabbed my attintion. Well i drank the whole damn bottle and didnt even get a buzz of it. It had good taste and a lil bit of a burn but nothing much. So last year for new years i made.a batch.of my own and damn that was some awsome stuff. So my guestion is this or somewhere in this next paragraph..

If i was to take 1 gallon of apple juice and 1 gallon of apple cider sugar brown sugar some cinn styx and 2 bottles 1/5 of course of grain alcohol wich is 190proof  or 90% abv each and a bottle 1/5 of cpt morgan spiced rum what would be the total proof of my apple pie?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about homebrewing.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be about homebrewing, and the answer cannot be determined from the information provided. Captain Morgan is available in various proofs.

Comment: This is a real-world question about dilution of alcohol, so it seems fair to ask it in Hombrewing. There are countries where home distilling is 100% legal (e.g. NZ), and dilution is a common exercise for the home brewer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a real-world question about dilution of alcohol, so it seems fair to ask it in Hombrewing.  There are countries where home distilling is 100% legal (e.g. NZ), and dilution is a common exercise for the home brewer.

There's a simple formula for dilution of alcohol with water.

To dilute an `start_volume` of `start_percent` AbV alcohol beverage to a `new_percent`:

```
Water_to_add = start_volume × (( start_percent ÷ new_percent ) - 1)
```

Source: https://homedistiller.org/calcs/dilute

For example, say I wish to dilute 3 litres of 90% AbV spirits down to 40% AbV ~

```
Water_to_add = 3 × ( ( 90 ÷ 40 ) - 1 )
Water_to_add = 3 × ( 2.25 - 1 )
Water_to_add = 3 × 1.25
             = 3.37 litres
```

We have to make some assumptions about your question, because you don't specify the size of a "bottle", and I don't understand what "1/5 cpt" means.  As a commenter pointed out we don't know the AbV of the "Spiced Rum" either.

So let the ingredients be:

- 2 bottles of 90% AbV (vodka) at 0.75 litres each (about 0.2 gal)

  - (So that's 1.5 litres of vodka)
- 1 bottle of 36% AbV rum at 0.75 litres (about 0.1 gal)
- 3.8 litres of juice (about 1 gal)
- whatever spices, they are too small in volume to be significant.

To work this out, convert the 90% vodka down to 36%.

```
 Juice = 1.5 × ( ( 90 ÷ 36 ) - 1 )
       = 2.25 litres. (Leaving 1.55 litres of juice to mix)
```

So now we have 3.75 litres of vodka-juice and 0.75 litres of rum (=4.5) both at 36%, and 1.55 litres of juice to dilute it. This is the same formula as above, except now we already know the amount to dilute with, but do not know the "desired" AbV.  So let's use the symbol  to denote "resultant AbV".

```
1.55  = 4.5 × ( ( 36 ÷  ) - 1 )
0.344 = ( 36 ÷  ) - 1
1.344 = 36 ÷ 
     = 36 ÷ 1.344
      = 26.78 % AbV
```

Another way to work this out is to simply calculate the amount of alcohol in each ingredient.

```
1.50 litres of vodka at 90% => 1.35 litres of alcohol + 0.15 other
0.75 litres of rum at 36%   => 0.27 litres of alcohol + 0.48 other
3.8  litres of juice at 0%  => 0.00 litres of alcohol + 3.8  other
```

This sums to 1.62 litres of alcohol and 4.43 litres of juice/water, giving a final combination of 1.62 litres in 6.05 litres

```
1.62 ÷ 6.05 = 26.78
            => 27% alcohol by volume
```

Note: I used USA Imperial volumetric conversions, not UK the version, since the USA is the only country still using these measurements AFAIK.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like your question includes ~8 litres of juice (although in most places in the world "cider" is an alcoholic beverage).  But you can re-calculate.  It rough class make this about 16%